# Magento how can I remove all products link from nav menu?

Tags: menu, navigation, magento-1.7

I want remove `All Products` link and title from my menu bar. I am using `<?php echo $_menu ?>` in navigation->top.phtml page. It shows all the categories title with link and `all products` title. I just want to show only the categories. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this.

thanks

Comment: Finally fixed issue. Actually I am using iphone theme for mobile version and they are using iphone.js file where they are used hard-coded 'All products' links in nav menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed issue. Actually I am using iphone theme for mobile version and they are using iphone.js file where they are used hard-coded 'All products' links in nav menu.